# Create Kafka Topics using node-rdkafka AdminClient

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am trying to create the Kafka Topic using the node-rdkafka AdminClient. But I am getting the below error. I am running this in Mac OS

```
Error: Local: Timed out
```

AdminClient:

```
const adminClient = Kafka.AdminClient.create({
        'security.protocol':'sasl_ssl',
        'bootstrap.servers': '*****:9092',
      'sasl.username': 'API Key',
      'sasl.password': 'API secret',
'sasl.mechanisms':'PLAIN'

adminClient.createTopic({
            topic: 'testTopic',
            num_partitions: 1,
            replication_factor: 1
          }, function(err) {
            // Done!
            console.log(`response::`+err);
          });
```

reference project: https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka

Comment: This is a common error when wither your bootstrap or your certs are incorrect. Are you able to produce or consume to already created topics?

Comment: Looks like some ssl cert issue. Not resolved, Found another node module to use that is kafkaJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue with my mac!

Solution:
Open a terminal and execute `ls /etc/ssl` and check whether `cert.pem` file exists.

If it exists, just add the following value next to `'sasl.mechanisms':'PLAIN'`

`'ssl.ca.location': '/etc/ssl/cert.pem'`
You have to pass in the cert.pem file's location

Your modified code should look like this

```
const adminClient = Kafka.AdminClient.create({
    'security.protocol':'sasl_ssl',
    'bootstrap.servers': '*****:9092',
    'sasl.username': 'API Key',
    'sasl.password': 'API secret',
    'sasl.mechanisms':'PLAIN',
    'ssl.ca.location': '/etc/ssl/cert.pem'
 })
```

Hope this works for you!